# Some modules doesn't load on boot up

Tags: ubuntu-core

I have tried to build my custom installation of ubuntu using Ubuntu-core. All work the way I wanted except some modules for my devices like my touchpad and wireless doesn't load automatically, so I have to load them manually using `modprobe` command. Why does this happend

Comment: Are you asking why this is happening? Or how can you make them load automatically? If you want them to load automatically on boot, add the names of the modules to /etc/modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Alla comments, you should just need to add the name of the module to `/etc/modules`.

```
sudo nano /etc/modules
```

Then add the name of your module (you can also specify parameters here) preferably before the `loop` module and if some driver depends of other, in the order the modules should be loaded. Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>. Reboot, and everything should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just run this command and put the modules name that you want to load automatically where it says modulename.

```
sudo su 

echo modulename >> /etc/modules 

exit
```